# Custom link layer protocol in UNIX

Tags: linux, drivers, kernel-modules, network-interface, c

I was wondering if someone has any info about how to implement a link layer portocol which uses the GPIOs (for example in a Raspberry Pi).

The idea is to implement a custom interface (similar to eth0) which would be point-to-point and when a message is sent through that interface instead of calling the ethernet module, my new kernel module (device driver) would be called which would use the GPIOs to send the packet.

I would like to know some stuff:

- Does anyone know of any book/paper/... with an example of something similar or info I would need to know? I found quite a lot of stuff on kernel modules and so, but nothing about "connecting" the new interface with the kernel module.
- Does it need to be implemented with TCP/IP if I want it to appear as a new interface? (I suppose the answer is yes)

My research lead me to some interesting webpages:

- Device driver implementation [example](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1032794/Simple-I-O-device-driver-for-RaspberryPi) for raspberry pi (controlling GPIOs).
- [RFC1149 Implementation](http://www.blug.linux.no/rfc1149/)

But still I'm quite lost when it comes to the interface implementation part, and how to "connect it" to the driver. So when I do a `ping` using the new interface, it sends the IP Packet to my device driver, so I should encapsulate it and send it through my hardware.

Thanks, hope to get some answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it's sufficient for your protocol to control the GPIO pins from userspace via `/sys/class/gpio/`, the simplest way is to write a userspace `tap` driver. From the kernel documentation `linux/Documentation/networking/tuntap.txt`:

> TUN/TAP provides packet reception and transmission for user space programs. 
>   It can be seen as a simple Point-to-Point or Ethernet device, which,
>   instead of receiving packets from physical media, receives them from 
>   user space program and instead of sending packets via physical media 
>   writes them to the user space program.
>
> In order to use the driver a program has to open `/dev/net/tun` and issue a
>   corresponding ioctl() to register a network device with the kernel. A network
>   device will appear as `tunXX` or `tapXX,` depending on the options chosen. When
>   the program closes the file descriptor, the network device and all
>   corresponding routes will disappear.
>
> Depending on the type of device chosen the userspace program has to read/write
>   IP packets (with tun) or ethernet frames (with tap). Which one is being used
>   depends on the flags given with the ioctl().
>
> The package from http://vtun.sourceforge.net/tun contains two simple examples
>   for how to use tun and tap devices. Both programs work like a bridge between
>   two network interfaces.
>
> - `br_select.c` - bridge based on select system call.
> - `br_sigio.c`  - bridge based on async io and SIGIO signal.
>
> However, the best example is VTun http://vtun.sourceforge.net :))

You can also google for lots of tutorials (though most will probably be about a `tun` interface, i.e. IP packets instead of Ethernet frames).

Even if the final product needs to be a kernel module, I'd still start out with a `tap` driver, because they are much easier to debug. You can still turn it into a kernel module after most of it already works.